# Scanner and StringTokenizer

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

I have a problem with this source when I use StringTokenizer and Scanner together.

This is the source:

```
package deberes.contador;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Contador {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escriba una frase: ");
        String mensaje = scan.next();
        StringTokenizer palabras = new StringTokenizer(mensaje);
        int nPalabras = palabras.countTokens();
        System.out.println(nPalabras);
    }
}
```

The result of `"nPalabras"` is always `"1"`, where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next()` returns only one complete token. Try `nextLine()` if you have many tokens.